# How to simply read binary digits from a socket in node js?

Tags: node.js, sockets, binary, buffer

In the code below, is there any way that I can simply log the binary data without converting to string?

```
var server  = net.createServer(function(sock) {

console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +':'+ sock.remotePort);


sock.on('data', function(data) {

    console.log('DATA ' + sock.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);

    sock.write('You said "' + data + '"');

});

sock.on('close', function(data) {
    console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +' '+ sock.remotePort);
});

})
```

Comment: What do you mean by binary data? At max you could get buffer. But what would you do with that unreadable buffer?

Answer (score 0):

Try code like this

```
server.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('data', function (bufferData) {
        console.log(bufferData);
    })
})
```